# Replace two objects in an expression

Tags: replacement

So I have a long expression that looks like this:

```
a (e1.e3)^2 (f1.e2)^2 + b (e1.e2)^2 (f1.e3)^2 + c e1.e3 e2.e3 f1.e2 f2.e1 + ...
```

What I want to do is to replace the first occurrence of, say, e1 with one term and the second with another, say x1 and y1. Furthermore, I would like the expression to be symmetric in the end. For example, I would like to have

```
(e1.e3)^2 --> x1.e3 y1.e3
```

and

```
e1.e3 e2.e3 f1.e2 f2.e1 --> x1.e3 e2.e3 f1.e2 f2.y1 + y1.e3 e2.e3 f1.e2 f2.x1
```

How do I come up with a replacement rule that will do the job?

Comment: Do you mean string, or do you mean expression? It looks like an expression to me, so you should change the title.

Comment: Thanks, @flinty! done.

Comment: Is there a typo in the first example ( shouldn't it be `(e1.e3)^2 --> x1.e3  +  y1.e3 `)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. Let us introduce two rules:

```
rule1 = {Dot[e1, a_]^2 :> x.a*y.a, Dot[a_, e1]^2 :> x.a*y.a};
rule2 = {Times[Dot[e1, a_], b___, Dot[c_, e1]] :> 
   Times[Dot[x, a], b, Dot[c, y]] + Times[Dot[y, a], b, Dot[c, x]], 
  Times[Dot[a_, e1], b___, Dot[c_, e1]] :> 
   Times[Dot[a, x], b, Dot[c, y]] + Times[Dot[a, y], b, Dot[c, x]],
  Times[Dot[a_, e1], b___, Dot[e1, c_]] :> 
   Times[Dot[a, x], b, Dot[y, c]] + Times[Dot[a, y], b, Dot[x, c]],
  Times[Dot[e1, a_], b___, Dot[c_, e1]] :> 
   Times[Dot[x, a], b, Dot[c, y]] + Times[Dot[y, a], b, Dot[c, x]]
  }
```

Let

```
expr=a (e1.e3)^2 (f1.e2)^2 + b (e1.e2)^2 (f1.e3)^2 + c e1.e3 e2.e3 f1.e2 f2.e1
```

be your expression. Then

```
expr /. rule1 /. rule2

(*  c e2.e3 f1.e2 f2.y x.e3 + b (f1.e3)^2 x.e2 y.e2 + 
 c e2.e3 f1.e2 f2.x y.e3 + a (f1.e2)^2 x.e3 y.e3  *)
```

Have fun!